# How can I convert a PDF from Google Docs to images? [or: GoogleDocs' PDF export is horrible!]

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, google-docs

I exported a document from Google Docs as PDF (just simple pages and one of the pre-defined themes) and, like I do usually, I used ImageMagick's *`convert`* to get pages converted to images, but it failed (even with the latest version) and showed no errors.
GhostScript also failed.
Other tools such as *`pdfinfo`*, *`mutool`* or *`qpdf`* don't report any error, yet it still fails even if `rebuild` or `clean` commands are applied.

Only *`pdfimages`* complains and gives me `Syntax Error: Missing or invalid Coords in shading dictionary`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried to reproduce some bugs, using Google Slides.

However, ***my*** bugs are different from ***yours***. Read on for some details...

Google Docs does indeed create a horrible PDF syntax today. I say *'today'*, because I gave up with Google Docs years ago. The reason: it was always very unstable for me in the past. GoogleDocs' developers seem to change the code they activate for users all the time, and debugging the created PDFs for me was always a moving target.

When I exported to PDF the slideshow I created, and then did run the tools you mentioned on it,...

### ... I got 4 different results within 20 minutes!

In one case, Mac OS X's *Preview.app* was unable to render anything else but 3 white pages, while Adobe's *Acrobat Pro* rendered it (without error message) somehow garbled and different from the GoogleDocs web preview.

In another case, Acrobat Pro showed 3 white pages, while Preview.app rendered it in a garbled way!

Unfortunately, I didn't save the different versions for closer inspection. The lastest PDF I analysed gave however the following details.

### Ghostscript:

```
pdfkungfoo@mbp:> gs -o PDFExportBug-%03d.jpg -sDEVICE=jpeg PDFExportBug.pdf
  GPL Ghostscript 9.10 (2013-08-30)
  Copyright (C) 2013 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
  This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
  Processing pages 1 through 3.
  Page 1
     **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
     **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
  Page 2
     **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
     **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
  Page 3
     **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
     **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.

     **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
     **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
     **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
     **** specification.
```

### ImageMagick:

`convert` creates white-only images from the PDF pages.

(That's no wonder because it does not process the PDFs directly, but employs Ghostscript as it's *delegate* to convert the PDF to a raster format first, which is then familiar ground for ImageMagick to continue with processing... **You can see details of this process by adding `-verbose` to your ImageMagick command line.**)

### `qpdf`

Using `qpdf --check` yields this result:

```
pdfkungfoo@mbp:> qpdf --check PDFExportBug.pdf
 qpdf --check PDFExportBug.pdf
 checking GoogleSlidesPDFExportBug.pdf
 PDF Version: 1.4
 File is not encrypted
 File is not linearized
 PDFExportBug.pdf (file position 9269):
      unknown token while reading object (0.0000-11728996)
```

### `pdfimages`:

Unlike what you discovered, my error message was this:

```
pdfkungfoo@mbp:> pdfimages -list PDFExportBug.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Syntax Warning (9276): Badly formatted number
Syntax Warning (9292): Badly formatted number
Syntax Warning (9592): Badly formatted number
Syntax Warning (9608): Badly formatted number
Syntax Warning (4907): Badly formatted number
Syntax Warning (4907): Badly formatted number
Syntax Warning (9908): Badly formatted number
Syntax Warning (9924): Badly formatted number
Syntax Warning (8212): Badly formatted number
Syntax Warning (8212): Badly formatted number
```

When I check with a text editor the file-offsets of `9276`, `9292`, ... `8212` for numbers, I indeed do find the following lines in the PDF code:

- Line 412: `0.0000-11728996`
- Line 413: `0.0000-11728996`
- Line 466: `0.0000-11728996`
- Line 467: `0.0000-11728996`
- Line 522: `0.0000-11728996`
- Line 523: `0.0000-11728996`

### PDF code in text editor:

Looking at the context of these lines, one sees the following:

```
32
0
obj
<<
/ShadingType
2
/ColorSpace
/DeviceRGB
/Function
<<
/FunctionType
2
/Domain
[
0
1
]
/Range
[
0
1
0
1
0
1
]
/C0
[
0.5882353
0.05882353
0.05882353
]
/C1
[
0.78431374
0.1254902
0.03529412
]
/N
1
>>
/Coords
[
0.000000000000053689468
0.0000
-11728996
0.0000
-11728996
26.832815
]
/Extend
[
true
true
]
>>
endobj
```

**That's true! GoogleDocs gave me a PDF that created a newline after each single token!**

### PDF code, if Google had formatted it less horribly:

These lines are part of a code snippet that ***should*** probably be formatted like this, if the Google PDF export wasn't as horrible as it in fact is:

```
32 0 obj
  <<
    /ShadingType    2    
    /ColorSpace     /DeviceRGB
    /Function       <<  /FunctionType   2
                        /Domain         [ 0 1 ]
                        /Range          [ 0 1 0 1 0 1 ]
                        /C0             [ 0.5882353 0.05882353 0.05882353 ]
                        /C1             [ 0.78431374 0.1254902 0.03529412 ]
                        /N              1    
                    >>   
    /Coords         [ 0.000000000000053689468 0.0000 -11728996 0.0000 -11728996 26.832815 ]
    /Extend         [ true true ]
  >>
endobj
```

**PDF code compared to the PDF specification:**

So GoogleDoc's PDF uses `/ShadingType 2` (for axial shading). This Shading Type requires a *'shading dictionary'* with an entry for the `/Coords` key that should have as value an array of 4 numbers `[x0 y0 x1 y1]`. These numbers would specify the starting and ending coordinates of the axis (expressed in the shading’s target coordinate space).

However, instead of a `/Coords` array of ***4*** numbers it uses one of ***6*** numbers: `[0.000000000000053689468 0.0000 -11728996 0.0000 -11728996 26.832815]`.

But Coords arrays with 6 numbers are to be used by `/ShadingType 3` (radial shading).

The 6 numbers `[x0 y0 r0 x1 y1 r1]` then represent, according to ISO 32000:

> *"[...] the centres and radii of the starting and ending circles, expressed in the shading’s target coordinate space. The radii r0 and r1 shall both be greater than or equal to 0. If one radius is 0, the corresponding circle shall be treated as a point; if both are 0, nothing shall be painted."*

15 minutes later, I exported the PDF again, but now I got these lines:

```
/Coords
[
0.000000000000053689468
0.0000-11728996
0.0000-11728996
26.832815
]
```

As you'll notice, now indeed the `/Coords` array has 4 entries -- but `0.0000-11728996` isn't a valid number!

In any case, the particular numbers in my objects 32, 33 and 34 do look funny somehow:

1. Either they are meant to be 6 numbers:
   `[0.000000000000053689468 0.0000 -11728996 0.0000 -11728996 26.832815]`

   1. Then they can only be meant for a `/ShadingType 3` (radial shading)
   2. But they are noted in the context of `/ShadingType 2` (axial shading)
2. Or they are meant to be 4 numbers:
   `[0.000000000000053689468 0.0000-11728996 0.0000-11728996 26.832815]`

   1. Then `0.0000-11728996` are not valid numbers.

### Fix

So the fix could be in...

1. ...either change the `/ShadingType 2` to `/ShadingType 3` and keep the array of 6 numbers
2. ...or keep the `/ShadingType 2` and throw away 2 of the 6 numbers to keep only 4 (but which?)

I decided (arbitrarily, by chance) to try with ShadingType 2 first and delete these two numbers: `-11728996 0.0000`.

I was lucky: the PDF now lets `convert` process the PDF pages into JPEGs (which means the Ghostscript command called by convert was also working correctly).

### Good luck with your continued using of GoogleDocs when creating PDFs...

...but don't count me in!

---

## Update

**[Here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1PZPckXAHmOCi5ygGovDD3H9x4sVPVRLyaKC1r43FSqM/edit?usp=sharing)** is a link to a GoogleDoc currently exhibiting one of the bug variants explained above:

[image: GoogleDocs PDF exporting bug]

To see the bug, save it as a PDF. Then open it in a text editor.

Should the doc from this link stop to export buggy PDFs and stop to exhibit one of the details I've described above, then Google has applied a fix... (*until they break it again?!?*)

Comment: While not standard and horrible, I don't believe separating tokens by returns is a *fault*. All whitespace types are allowed, including a binary zero (!). I'll have a look at your test doc, though.

Comment: @Jongware: I didn't use the word 'fault' in the context of the separated tokens, or did I? ;-)

Comment: Your wording suggest it's **not good!!** ... Anyhow -- I can confirm your shady `/Shading` finds with my own tool: `Unexpected new object at end of object 80`. Seems Google forgot to clear some buffer or something like that.

Comment: @Jongware: I'm curious -- which is "my own tool" that you are using?

Comment: One I wrote from scratch, in plain C, using the last PDF Reference as a guide. 'Twas loads of fun, and still occasionally pretty useful.